# jquery hover not working with css class selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use the *phoneNumberIcon* css class to control visibility on hover for the div. But I also want to initially hide div with a different css class named *editIcon*.

```
#div1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}

.editIcon {
  display: none;
}

<div id="div1" class="editIcon phoneNumberIcon"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  //$(".phoneNumberIcon").show();

  $("#div1").hover(function() {
    $(".phoneNumberIcon").show();
  }, function() {
    $(".phoneNumberIcon").hide();
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6entpxbk/6/

Comment: And the question is? Dude, it's not google

Comment: Anyway you are trying to change visibility of .phoneNumberIcon, and there is no rule .phoneNumberIcon{display:none}

Comment: UPDATE: This is basically what I was trying to do. For some reason it wasn't working. I had some other css conflicts preventing the icons from showing on hover: https://jsfiddle.net/6entpxbk/38/

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because `#div1` and `.editIcon.phoneNumberIcon` it the same element and you set it to display `none` with your CSS, therefore there's nothing to hover over.

You could put the icon inside your `#div1` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$(".phoneNumberIcon").show();

  $("#div1").hover(function() {
    $(".phoneNumberIcon").show();
  }, function() {
    $(".phoneNumberIcon").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
#div1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}

.editIcon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div class="editIcon phoneNumberIcon">icon</div>
</div>
```

Also this could be easily done without using JavaScript:

```css
#div1 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}

.editIcon {
  display: none;
}

#div1:hover .editIcon {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div class="editIcon phoneNumberIcon">icon</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and Javascript don't make sense. The box is hidden because you applied the `editIcon` class to it, hiding it. You're basically (boiling it down) hiding an element, then trying to hover over it.  You need to apply the `phoneNumberIcon` class to an element **inside** the `div`, and not the `div` itself. 
**Another thing**: if you want icons, then use Font Awesome, it's very popular with web devs nowadays.

[Here's a fiddle showing what I mean, with the Font Awesome library.](https://jsfiddle.net/4mq1gyw2/6/)

Here's a working version of your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$(".phoneNumberIcon").show();

  $("#div1").hover(function() {
    $(".phoneNumberIcon").show();
  }, function() {
    $(".phoneNumberIcon").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="editIcon">
  <div class="phoneNumberIcon">
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
```

You should learn HTML, as your code suggests your knowledge of it is not solid. [A quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=html+courses&t=ironbrowser&ia=web) will get you back on track.

Comment: The div is being hidden by .editIcon, not .phoneNumberIcon. I want to use .editIcon to initially hide #div1 and another other divs that may refer to it, but I only want to use .phoneNumberIcon to show/hide only #div1 with .hover().

Comment: Didn't my answer cover that?

Comment: The div needs to be initially hidden preferably with CSS so it never shows up during page load. This can apply to multiple divs through the page. That is what .editIcon is for. But when I hover, I only want to show/hide the div that has .phoneNumberIcon. I'm understanding now that what is happening is initially hiding the div in CSS with display:none causes .hover() to not even find the div.

Comment: If you want to show them on page-load, check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tb56ep4k/2/

Comment: Your question is very confusing.